# Java Applet Excessive Flickering

Tags: java, swing, paint, japplet, mouse-listeners

I'm creating a simple shooting gallery type game. I have create a mouse motion listener and am using to draw an image at the current position of the mouse. This works fine however the image flicker quite a lot when I move the cursor. I have tried several double buffering tutorial however none of these work.

Here is my code

```
    public class ShootingGallery extends JApplet implements MouseMotionListener {

        //VARIABLES
        int mouseXPos;
        int mouseYPos;
        Image myImage;
        private Image dbImage;
        private Graphics dbg;

        @Override
        public void init() {            
            setSize(800, 600);//SET UP CURSOR IMAGE
            myImage = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"spongebob.gif");
            addMouseMotionListener(this);//ADD ACTION LISTENERS
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {            
            moveMouse(e); 
        }        

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {            
            moveMouse(e);
        }        

        public void moveMouse(MouseEvent e){            
              Graphics g = getGraphics();             
              mouseXPos = e.getX() - (myImage.getWidth(null) / 2);
              mouseYPos = e.getY() - (myImage.getHeight(null) / 2);     
              repaint();
        } 

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
              super.paint(g);            
              g.drawImage(myImage, mouseXPos, mouseYPos, this);
        }
   }
```

Any help with this issue is much appreciated

Comment: Rather than repainting the whole screen `repaint` only the part that will be changed.

Comment: I'm fairly new to java how exactly would I do this?

Comment: @ExtremeCoders The repaint manager is normally pretty good at figuring this out and clips graphics context accordingly, but top level contacts are not double buffered which is the key source of the problem

Comment: could you provide any code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing is already supported buffering.  Just paint on another container not the top-level one, please see code here:

```
public class ShootingGallery extends JApplet implements MouseMotionListener {

// VARIABLES
int mouseXPos;
int mouseYPos;
Image myImage;

@Override
public void init() {
    setSize(800, 600);// SET UP CURSOR IMAGE
    myImage = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "spongebob.gif");
    addMouseMotionListener(this);// ADD ACTION LISTENERS
    this.add(new PaintContainer());

}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    moveMouse(e);
    repaint();
}

public void moveMouse(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseXPos = e.getX() - (myImage.getWidth(null) / 2);
    mouseYPos = e.getY() - (myImage.getHeight(null) / 2);
}

public class PaintContainer extends JPanel {

     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         g.drawImage(myImage, mouseXPos, mouseYPos, this);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: This stops the flickering but is there no way to do it without creating a sub class

Answer (score 0):

A mouse motion listener will be called very frequently as the mouse passes over the screen, possibly as often as once per transited pixel.  If you draw an image that often, your code may not be able to keep up, causing it to flicker.

Comment: ok is there a workaround? I tried using the toolkit to actually change the cursor to an image. While this worked the maximum allowed size was far to small. I'm trying to create the same effect through different means that will allow me to have a much larger image.